# Can "old man" be used by females to address unrelated older men?

Tags: grammatical-gender

I'm a fan-translator, translating from Oriental languages to English, and I've been told to translate "uncle" to "old man", since a direct translation would imply a familial relation where there was none.

I just discovered that Google gives one of the definitions of "old man" as "an affectionate form of address between men or boys." But none of the dictionary sites say anything about "between men or boys," just something along the lines of "an affectionate term used in addressing a man." So have I been using it wrong, or is it okay for females to use the term too?

Comment: "Old man" is not necessarily an affectionate, nor even a neutral term in English.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/468719/2303)

Comment: Yeah, I edited it to "address."

Comment: Please update your question with the specific sentence you are contemplating and also include a description of the feeling you wish it to invoke.

Comment: As terms of endearment between males "old man" and "old boy" are very dated (at least in British English) and even when they were in frequent use I believe that they were more common in middle and upper class speech than in working class speech. The equivalent working class expression is probably "mate". I certainly wouldn't expect to hear a young woman use either term to address a middle aged man. It would certainly be odd and might be taken as offensive.

Comment: In some (!) situations, a young woman may address an old stranger fondly as "grandpa".

Comment: Western cultures tend not to have the same respect for elders as oriental cultures do. Therefore, "old man" or any variations of it are likely to have a more negative connotation than you would want. Since this is such a difficult term to translate exactly, you should refine your question with specific examples.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, from my region near Appalachia, women use "Old Man" in reference to their father or husband/significant other.  I wouldn't use it in a translation unless the people were from a region in America where it is used.  I think too sometimes it is used by lower socio-economical families.  A woman may describe a stranger as an old man, but she would not call him such when talking to him.  It's more like a term of endearment.  I have heard children referring to their parents friends as "uncles" or "aunts" as a term of respect, which did cause some confusion about cousins on the playground.  We would not call a stranger uncle.  If you gave us more context of the sentence you are working on, we may be able to help find the correct term used in conversations.

Comment: The question specifically talks about _addressing_ someone as ‘old man’, which is quite different from talking about ‘my old man’ (husband, father). Even in places where a woman might well refer to her dad as her old man, she’d be very unlikely to say, “Excuse me, old man, can you help me?”, unless she actually wanted to come across as rude.

Answer (score -1):

Note: This was made before this comment from OP:

> Ah, I wasn't referring to "uncle" in English as in a relative, but in Asian languages like Japanese, where it is normal to call any middle-aged man "uncle." So in English I just translate it to "old man" to refer to unrelated older men affectionately.

---

I've heard "old man" used for "father", although, mainly from sons, not daughters.

Its use for uncles at all, is new to me.

---

I think, "Uncle" as a affectionate term, is usually used for family friends, usually mainly through the parents, as to have an "uncle-like" familiarity with them or something.

---

Give an example sentence and its translation, and we can decide further?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't referring to "uncle" in English as in a relative, but in Asian languages like Japanese, where it is normal to call any middle-aged man "uncle." So in English I just translate it to "old man" to refer to unrelated older men affectionately.

Comment: @xiiliea I believe that there is no way to translate "uncle" used this way into English and have it sound like natural English, we just don't have a tradition of addressing unrelated people in that way. A family friend might be addressed as "Uncle Fred" if his name was Fred but never just as "uncle". However I believe that most English speakers would accept "uncle" in translation understanding that the usage was native to the original context. They would probably accept "grandmother" for an old lady in the same way although it would be pretty offensive in most English-speaking countries.

Comment: When I was young (UK 1950s/60s) it was considered _very_ bad manners for a child to address an adult by just their given name, but, as BoldBen says, family friends could be called 'Uncle Fred' or the like. I agree that the literal translation is your best bet.

Comment: @KateBunting - So, you would've used their full name? Well, I guess it makes sense, you weren't really close enough to them to do otherwise, and didn't encounter them enough for that to be weird? You'd have been a kid?

Comment: @Malandy Yes, I'm talking about my childhood. We were taught to call grownups 'Mr Smith' or 'Mrs Brown', but some family friends were treated as honorary uncles and aunts.